# Forcing HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to cancel after a certain time

Tags: c#, asp.net, background-process, cancellation-token

I am running non-async/await code like this

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(x => CallApi());
```

I have seen examples of using a cancellation token being used to cancel the request, if my CallApi method takes say more than 10 seconds to complete, is there a way to cancel the whole request and log some output? I can't find an example where a specific timeout has been set

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx might be interesting

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation is cooperative. Cancelling an "uncancelable" operation is very awkward.

If `CallApi` takes a `CancellationToken`, then you can just construct one using `CancellationTokenSource` that cancels after a given time.

If `CallApi` doesn't take a `CancellationToken` but operates on some kind of `HANDLE`-based object, then you can try cancelling by closing the underlying `HANDLE`. This is a common (but not universal) way to cancel operations that may not otherwise be cancelable.

Otherwise, `CallApi` is an uncancelable operation, which means you're looking at some awkward code.

The most reliable way to cancel an uncancelable operation is to place the code in a separate process, and terminate that process on cancellation.

However, since you're on ASP.NET already, you could also look at placing the code in a separate AppDomain or thread, and unloading the AppDomain / terminating the thread on cancellation. Over time, this will cause process instability, but ASP.NET will recycle your process periodically, so it should (eventually) recover.